# Function and include

Tags: php, function, include

I have one file called paths.php that has the following code :

```
<?php

$path_1="db";
$path_2="files";

?>
```

This file is included in other files, for example file index.php and the following include : `include("paths.php");`

In index.php, where I got this include, I also have the following function :

```
<?php
function explode($value,$separator)
{
    /// Into I need take value $path_1 ///
    $exp=explode("$separator","$value");
    for ($i=0;$i<count($exp);$i++)
    {
        print "".$exp[$i]."";
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that I need to the read the value ($value) from the include inside the function scope. I have problems with the function, the include has to be in the function to work.

Is it possible that the function take these values and do not need the include to be inside the function, because if I don't put the include inside it doesn't take correct values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean. But I noticed some problem in your code:

```
function explode($value,$separator)
{
```

[explode()](http://php.net/explode) is a built-in PHP function. You cannot redeclare it. You need to use a different function name for your function.

If you wish to access `$path_1` and `$path_2` from inside a function you created, you need to use [`global`](http://php.net/global). For example:

```
function custom_explode($value,$separator) {
    global $path_1, $path_2;
    // your other codes
    echo 'I can now access $path_1: '.$path_1.' and $path_2: '.$path_2.'!';
}
```